# How to compute error on forecasting on Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to compute the error between a list `d[]` of real value and a list `p[]` of predicted one, but it doesn't work. is there any simple way to compute it through a library, for instance scikit-learn?

```
x=0
def error(x):

    a = 1
    while len (d)-1<30 and len(p)-1< 30:
        x = d[a-1] - p[a-1]
        d.append(x)
        a = a + 1
    return d[30:]


print(error(x))
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from your question I think you looking for something like this :

first if you use python list convert it to numpy array it make faster your computation in comparing , from the For loop you just use :

```
real = np.asanarray(real)
predicted = np.asanarray(predicted)
```

after that :

```
score = np.nonzero((real == predicted)) / (# number of your sample)
```

`(real == predicted)` this will give you an array of `boolean` that show if the prediction matches the real value or not

and by counting non_zero value you just count the successful prediction

this approach is yous for classification problem but with a little change in syntax you could get what you wanted !